# Memory leak with unsigned char *

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method where I return `unsigned char *`:

```
- (unsigned char *)calledMethod {
    ...
    unsigned char *result = (unsigned char*) calloc(size * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    ...
    return result;
}
```

The problem is, when I call this method:

```
unsigned char *myVariable = [myClass calledMethod];
```

I get a memory leak.

How should I free the memory?

I've already tried `free(myVariable)`, but no use. If I would call `free(result)` in my `calledMethod` method, there would be no leak, but then I cannot return it. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The problem is, I am storing in that `myVariable` the pixel data of a UIImage (4 components for each `CGPoint`:rgba). I have to modify some of the pixels and reconstruct the image. I am accessing the data of a point like this:

```
int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * point.y) + point.x * bytesPerPixel;
CGFloat red   = (myVariable[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
CGFloat green = (myVariable[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
CGFloat blue  = (myVariable[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
CGFloat alpha = (myVariable[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
```

If I use `NSMutableData`, what would be the `length` parameter in `[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:(const void *) length:(NSUInteger)]` and how would I modify the data of a given `CGPoint`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`free()` is the correct function to call to free up the memory.  If you still have the memory leak, you are either not calling `free()` at all, or you are not calling it enough.  For example, the following would leak:

```
myVariable = [foo calledMethod];
// some stuff
myVariable = [foo calledMethod];
// more stuff
free(myVariable);
```

Might I suggest that, instead of using a raw buffer like this, you use an [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html). That way, you'll get the benefit of whatever Objective-C memory management method you are using.

Comment: @Levi The length is the number of bytes you want in the NSMutableData.  This is the same as the number of bytes you would have calloced. i.e. `size * 4 * sizeof(unsigned char)` (unsigned char is of size 1, so you could use `size * 4` )

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct. You return an malloc-ed block of memory that you assign to `myVariable` and later free it using `free(myVariable)`. The code that you are showing us is not responsible for the leak. Perhaps it lies in the `...`?. What does static analysis tell you?

Comment: Haven't tried static analysis. Only checked it in instruments

Answer (score 1):

Calling `free` when you are done will deallocate the memory. Are you sure you instrumented things correctly when you tried calling `free(myVariable)`? That should work.

Comment: Yes, every time i call the method the total allocantions are increased by 6 MB. If I free the memory in my `calledMethod`, everything looks fine.

Comment: @Levi But are you really getting a memory leak?

Comment: @Sulthan I "left" the method, have no reference to that data anymore, but the Instruments still indicates the allocated memory.

Comment: @Levi Well, that doesn't mean it's a leak. If the memory is freed in the same method, the compiler can create some clever optimizations and reuse that memory when the method is called for the 2nd time. Freeing the memory doesn't mean it will get returned to the system immediately. Use "Leak Analyzer" Instrument to detect leaks. Increased allocated memory doesn't automatically mean a leak.

Comment: @Sulthan Indeed, the Leak analyser doesn't show me any leaks. However, when I run the app on a device (just to have smaller memory to work with) and keep calling that method, I eventually get memory warning and a crash (the call of the method is on the users interaction)

Comment: @Levi Then the best solution is to reuse the memory you have already allocated, if you are calling the method multiple times.

Comment: Modern day allocators can do many small malloc/frees extremely efficiently, so reusing buffers isn't required unless there is a measurable performance improvement. Anyway, this whole discussion is pointless because calling `free` does indeed release memory allocated from `calloc`. The OP must have misinterpreted Instruments' data or failed to implement it correctly.